# Maat: Sleigh raised a bad data exception: r0x00000002: Unable to resolve constructor

Tags: python, symbolic-execution, maat

I'm running the [maat](https://maat.re/tutorials/get_started.html) symbolic executor on my Linux instance with the following code.

Command I ran to get my binary code:

```bash
gcc myFile.c -o myFile.out
```

Maat python code:

```py
from maat import MaatEngine, ARCH, OS, BIN
m = MaatEngine(ARCH.X64, OS.LINUX)
m.load("./myFile.out", BIN.ELF64, args=[b"hello"], load_interp=False)
m.run()
```

However, running this is getting me the following error:

```
$ python3 symbolic.py 
[Warning] Couldn't find library 'libc.so.6': skipping import
[Warning] Missing imported function: __cxa_finalize
[Info] Adding object './myFile.out' to virtual fs at '/./myFile.out'
[Error] Sleigh failed to decode instructions in basic block starting at 0x2. Raised the following error: "Sleigh raised a bad data exception: r0x00000002: Unable to resolve constructor"
[Error] Lifter error: MaatEngine::get_asm_inst(): failed to lift instructions
```

What's going on?